# Java: Fill bidimensional array or nested lists with permutation of dates allowing null and repeated values only considering precedence (not values)

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, comparison, permutation

I am doing operations with **`n`** number of dates and I want to fill a **`n`**`x`**`m`** array that contains all permutations considering the following:

- The driver of the permutations has to be the dates' precedence, not values
- Null and duplicates/repetitions are allowed
- Do not have duplicate permutations
- Dates are defined, not provided (this implementation detail outside the scope of question)

### Current work:

So far I split the problem in 3 general cases:

- Permutations without null values and without duplicates.
- Permutations with null values but without duplicates.
- Rest of permutations (need help with this one).

### Example to clarify the situation:

I have `4` dates that correspond to the dates of birth of: `Tim`, `Zoe`, `Liz` and `Ben`.

I want to know all the permutations for parallel universes in respect of who was born before who (date values are relatively relevant). In case of `null`, it would indicate that the person was not born; and in case of duplicates, they mean that people were born at the same date.

I split the the problem in 3 parts. I also represented the dates as numbers so I can have the representation in an array with numbers and later I can just translate those numbers to a date (maybe randomized or maybe as a part of an list of enumerated values).

As example, I will have the following enumerated dates:

```
1 = 2018-01-01
2 = 2019-01-01
3 = 2020-01-01
4 = 2021-01-01
```

The permutations for the **1st part** of the problem (permutations ***without null values*** and ***without duplicates***) should look like:

```
[ Tim , Zoe , Liz , Ben ]
[  1  ,  2  ,  3  ,  4  ]
[  1  ,  2  ,  4  ,  3  ]
[  1  ,  3  ,  2  ,  4  ]
[  1  ,  3  ,  4  ,  2  ]
[  1  ,  4  ,  3  ,  2  ]
[  1  ,  4  ,  2  ,  3  ]
[  2  ,  1  ,  3  ,  4  ]
  ...[16 more rows]...
[  4  ,  1  ,  2  ,  3  ]
```

For the **2nd part** of the problem, we can substitute any single number with null throughout all permutations from previous step and we would still be consistent. The example would be as follows:

```
[ Tim , Zoe , Liz , Ben ]
[  ␀ ,  2  ,  3  ,  4  ]
[  ␀ ,  2  ,  4  ,  3  ]
[  ␀ ,  3  ,  2  ,  4  ]
[  ␀ ,  3  ,  4  ,  2  ]
[  ␀ ,  4  ,  3  ,  2  ]
[  ␀ ,  4  ,  2  ,  3  ]
[  2  , ␀  ,  3  ,  4  ]
  ...[16 more rows]...
[  4 ,  ␀  ,  2  ,  3  ]
```

**Could you please help me with the following part:**

> The tricky part is including repeated values to indicate that more
>   than one person was born the same date. See the examples below:
>
> > This indicates that Tim, Zoe and Liz were born the same date and they are younger than Ben.
> >
> > ```
> > [ Tim , Zoe , Liz , Ben ]
> > [  1  ,  1  ,  1  ,  2  ]
> > ```
>
> ---
>
> > This indicates that Tim and Zoe were born the same date and they are elder than Ben; and Ben is elder than Liz.
> >
> > ```
> > [ Tim , Zoe , Liz , Ben ]
> > [  3  ,  3  ,  1  ,  2  ]
> > ```
> >
> > ---
> >
> > **Both rows below** express that Tim, Zoe and Liz were born the same date and they are younger than Ben, but **only the first one is correct** because it shows the precedence of the events in the correct sequence.
> >
> > ```
> > [ Tim , Zoe , Liz , Ben ]
> > [  1  ,  1  ,  1  ,  2  ]
> > [  1  ,  1  ,  1  ,  3  ]
> > ```

**Code for 1st and 2nd parts of the problem**

```java
public class Permuter {
    static void permute(List<Integer> list, int recursionNestingLevel, List<List<Integer>> results){
        for (int listIndex = recursionNestingLevel; listIndex < list.size(); listIndex++){
            Collections.swap(list, listIndex, recursionNestingLevel);
            permute(list, recursionNestingLevel + 1, results);
            Collections.swap(list, recursionNestingLevel, listIndex);
        }
        if (recursionNestingLevel == list.size() - 1){
            results.add(new ArrayList<>(list));
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Integer> listForPermutation = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4);
        List<List<Integer>> permutations = new ArrayList<>();
        Permuter.permute(listForPermutation, 0, permutations);
        System.out.println("Permutations without null values and without duplicates:");
        System.out.println(permutations.stream().map(list -> list.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator())));
        List<List<Integer>> permutationsWithNulls = permutations.stream().map(list -> list.stream().map(i -> i == 1 ? null : i).collect(Collectors.toList())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println("Permutations without null values and without duplicates:");
        System.out.println(permutationsWithNulls.stream().map(list -> list.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator())));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was splitting the problem in 2 general cases, each one with 2 variants. The general cases are:

**1. Permutations without repetitions.**

```
    [ Eli , Dex , Eva ]
    [  1  ,  2  ,  3  ]
    [  1  ,  3  ,  2  ]
    [  2  ,  1  ,  3  ]
    [  2  ,  3  ,  1  ]
    [  3  ,  1  ,  2  ]
    [  3  ,  2  ,  1  ]
```

**2. Permutations with repetitions.**

```
    [ Eli , Dex , Eva ]
    [  1  ,  1  ,  1  ]
    [  1  ,  1  ,  2  ]
    [  1  ,  2  ,  1  ]
    [  2  ,  1  ,  1  ]
    [  2  ,  2  ,  1  ]
    [  2  ,  1  ,  2  ]
    [  1  ,  2  ,  2  ]
```

I decided to represent `null` values with `0`, therefore the following variants:

**1.1. Permutations without repetitions but with `null` values.**

```
    [ Eli , Dex , Eva ]
    [  0  ,  1  ,  2  ]
    [  0  ,  2  ,  1  ]
    [  1  ,  0  ,  2  ]
    [  1  ,  2  ,  0  ]
    [  2  ,  0  ,  1  ]
    [  2  ,  1  ,  0  ]
```

**2.1. Permutations with repetitions and `null` values.**

```
    [ Eli , Dex , Eva ]
    [  0  ,  0  ,  0  ]
    [  0  ,  0  ,  1  ]
    [  0  ,  1  ,  0  ]
    [  1  ,  0  ,  0  ]
    [  1  ,  1  ,  0  ]
    [  1  ,  0  ,  1  ]
    [  0  ,  1  ,  1  ]
```

After generating the above numeric representations, displaying the data with dates is just matter of substituting numbers with date strings and zeroes with nulls.

The class **Combinatorics.java** calculates what I call "Precedence Model" by running permutations on arrays. Run the `main` method of this class to generate the numeric representation of dates based on precedence which can be translated to dates based on simple hard-coded values or dynamically generated ones.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Combinatorics {

    PrecedenceModel precedenceModel;

    public Combinatorics(int elementCount) {
        this.precedenceModel = new PrecedenceModel(elementCount);
    }

    public PrecedenceModel getPrecedenceModel() {
        return precedenceModel;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates all permutations of elements given in <b>{@code array}</b> recursively
     */
    public static void permute(int[] array, int nestingLevel, Set<List<Integer>> results, Predicate<int[]> filter){

        if (nestingLevel == array.length) {
            if(filter.test(array)) {
                results.add(Arrays.stream(array).boxed().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)));             
            }
            return;
        }

        permute(array, nestingLevel + 1, results, filter);

        for (int index = nestingLevel + 1; index < array.length; index++) {
            if (array[index] == array[nestingLevel]) {
                continue;
            }
            array = array.clone();
            int temp = array[index];
            array[index] = array[nestingLevel];
            array[nestingLevel] = temp;
            permute(array, nestingLevel + 1, results, filter);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Calculates all   permutations of elements given in <b>{@code array}</b> recursively
     */
    public Set<List<Integer>> getPermutations(int[] array, Predicate<int[]> filter){

        Set<List<Integer>> results = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        permute(array, 0, results, filter);
        return results;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates all permutations with repeated values based on
     * the base matrix of the precedence model's matrices
     */
    public Set<List<Integer>> getPermutationsWithRepetitions(int[][] precedenceModelMatrix, Predicate<int[]> filter){

        Set<List<Integer>> permutationsWithRepetitions = new LinkedHashSet<>();

        if(filter.test(precedenceModelMatrix[precedenceModelMatrix.length - 1])) {
            permutationsWithRepetitions.add(
                Arrays.stream(precedenceModelMatrix[precedenceModelMatrix.length - 1])
                        .boxed().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)));
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < (precedenceModelMatrix.length - 1); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < precedenceModelMatrix.length; j++) {
                int array[] = precedenceModelMatrix[i].clone();
                permutationsWithRepetitions.addAll(getPermutations(array, filter));
                for (int k = 0; k < i + 1; k++) {
                    array[k] = j - i + precedenceModelMatrix[0][0];
                }
                array[j] = precedenceModelMatrix[0][0];
                permutationsWithRepetitions.addAll(getPermutations(array, filter));
            }
        }

        return permutationsWithRepetitions;
    }

    private Set<List<Integer>> getPrecedenceModel(PermutationType ... permutationTypes){
        return getPrecedenceModel((a -> true), permutationTypes);
    }

    public Set<List<Integer>> getPrecedenceModel(PermutationType permutationTypes, Predicate<int[]> filter){
        return getPrecedenceModel(filter, permutationTypes);
    }

    private Set<List<Integer>> getPrecedenceModel(Predicate<int[]> filter, PermutationType ... permutationTypes){
        Set<List<Integer>> result = new LinkedHashSet<>();

        Set<PermutationType> permTypes = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(permutationTypes));
        System.out.println(permTypes);
        Set<List<Integer>> simplePermutations = null;
        Set<List<Integer>> permutationsWithRepetitions = null;
        Set<List<Integer>> permutationsWithSingleParameter = null;
        Set<List<Integer>> permutationsWithParameterRepetitions = null;
        if(permTypes.contains(PermutationType.ALL_PERMUTATIONS)) {
            simplePermutations = getPermutations(getPrecedenceModel().getBaseMatrix()[0], filter);
            permutationsWithRepetitions = getPermutationsWithRepetitions(getPrecedenceModel().getBaseMatrix(), filter);
            permutationsWithParameterRepetitions = getPermutationsWithRepetitions(getPrecedenceModel().getParameterMatrix(), filter);
            permutationsWithSingleParameter = getPermutations(getPrecedenceModel().getParameterMatrix()[0], filter);

            result.addAll(simplePermutations);
            result.addAll(permutationsWithRepetitions);
            result.addAll(permutationsWithParameterRepetitions);
            result.addAll(permutationsWithSingleParameter);

            return result;
        }
        if(permTypes.contains(PermutationType.SIMPLE_PERMUTATIONS)) {
            simplePermutations = getPermutations(getPrecedenceModel().getBaseMatrix()[0], filter);
            result.addAll(simplePermutations);
        }
        if(permTypes.contains(PermutationType.PERMUTATION_WITH_REPETITIONS)) {
            permutationsWithRepetitions = getPermutationsWithRepetitions(getPrecedenceModel().getBaseMatrix(), filter);
            result.addAll(permutationsWithRepetitions);
        }
        if(permTypes.contains(PermutationType.PERMUTATION_WITH_PARAMETER_REPETITIONS)) {
            permutationsWithParameterRepetitions = getPermutationsWithRepetitions(getPrecedenceModel().getParameterMatrix(), filter);
            result.addAll(permutationsWithParameterRepetitions);
        }
        if(permTypes.contains(PermutationType.PERMUTATION_WITH_SINGLE_PARAMETER)) {
            permutationsWithSingleParameter = getPermutations(getPrecedenceModel().getParameterMatrix()[0], filter);
            result.addAll(permutationsWithSingleParameter);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Combinatorics combinatorics = new Combinatorics(3);
//      Set<List<Integer>> precedenceModelBypass = combinatorics.getPermutations(new int[] {1,2,3}, (a -> true));
//      System.out.println(ApiUtils.collectionToStringN1Dn(precedenceModelBypass));

        Set<List<Integer>> precedenceModel = combinatorics.getPrecedenceModel(
//                  PermutationType.ALL_PERMUTATIONS//3(6)
//                  ,
                    PermutationType.SIMPLE_PERMUTATIONS//3(6)
                    ,
                    PermutationType.PERMUTATION_WITH_REPETITIONS//3(7)
//                  ,
//                  PermutationType.PERMUTATION_WITH_PARAMETER_REPETITIONS//3(7)
//                  ,
//                  PermutationType.PERMUTATION_WITH_SINGLE_PARAMETER//3(6)
                    );
        System.out.println(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.repeat('-', 200));
        System.out.println("Numeric Model. Count: " + precedenceModel.size());
        System.out.println(ApiUtils.collectionToStringN1Dn(precedenceModel));
    }
}
```

The class **PrecedenceModel.java** generates a couple of square matrices based on the number of elements needed that will be used to calculate the premutations.

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class PrecedenceModel {

    private int elementCount;
    private int[][] baseMatrix;
    private int[][] parameterMatrix;

    public PrecedenceModel(int elementCount) {
        this.elementCount = elementCount;
        setBaseMatrix(elementCount);
        setParameterMatrix(elementCount);
    }

    public int getElementCount() {
        return elementCount;
    }

    public int[][] getBaseMatrix() {
        return baseMatrix;
    }

    public void setBaseMatrix(int elementCount) {
        baseMatrix = new int[elementCount][elementCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < elementCount; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < elementCount; j++) {
                baseMatrix[i][j] = (j <= i) ? 1 : j + 1 - i; 
            }
        }
    }

    public int[][] getParameterMatrix() {
        return parameterMatrix;
    }

    public void setParameterMatrix(int elementCount) {
        parameterMatrix = new int[elementCount][elementCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < elementCount; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < elementCount; j++) {
                parameterMatrix[i][j] = (j <= i) ? 0 : j - i; 
            }
        }
    }

    @SafeVarargs
    public static <T> Map<T, Integer> toMap(T ... values) {
        Map<T, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>(values.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            map.put(values[i], i);
        }

        return map;
    }
}
```

The class **PermutationType.java** will be used to classify the different permutations we can obtain. It's attribute `isParameterRequired` will indicate if the matrix has zeroes which I consider as 'parameter' values because we can substitute them with `null` values or any other values later on.

```
public enum PermutationType {
    SIMPLE_PERMUTATIONS (false),
    PERMUTATION_WITH_SINGLE_PARAMETER (true),
    PERMUTATION_WITH_PARAMETER_REPETITIONS (true),
    PERMUTATION_WITH_REPETITIONS (false),
    ALL_PERMUTATIONS (true);

    private boolean isParameterRequired;

    private PermutationType(boolean isParameterRequired) {
        this.isParameterRequired = isParameterRequired;
    }
    public boolean isParameterRequired() {
        return isParameterRequired;
    }
}
```

Here's a little bit more on the class **PrecedenceModel.java**. The 2 matrices `baseMatrix` and `parameterMatrix` generated by this class will look like:

**`baseMatrix`**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

**`parameterMatrix`**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 0, 1, 2]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```

The `baseMatrix` will be used to calculate numeric representation of dates **without** `null` values (or parameters). The `parameterMatrix` will be used to calculate numeric representation of dates **with** `null` values (or parameters).

The first row of any matrix is used to calculate all ***permutations without repetitions***.

> Tricky part coming...

Second to last rows are used to calculate ***permutations with repetitions only***. Values of each one of those rows will be reshuffled to produce distinct precedences and everyone of those results will be permutated to get the final resut of all posible permutations with repetitions. E.g. let's take the **2nd** row of the `baseMatrix` :

```
[1, 1, 2, 3] <- contains 2 repeated values
```

To get the different precedences of that row I shuffle the precedence of the repeated elements (1,1) with every of the non-repeated. This can be done by shifting values like:

```
 >>>>>>>
 ^  ^  v
 ^  ^  v
[1, 1, 2, 3] <- contains 2 repeated values
 ^  ^  v
 ^  ^  v
 <<<<<<<
```

The different precedences for **2nd** row of the `baseMatrix` are:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3]
[2, 2, 1, 3]
[1, 1, 2, 3]
[3, 3, 2, 1]
```

Then all the permutations of all different precedences for **2nd** row have to be calculated.

To finalize, all of the above procedures for **2nd** have to be applied for **3rd** row as well. And as **4th** row (boundary case) contains all repeated elements, no operation has to be run against it.

The following bonus class is just a sample of the process I use to calculate the base matrix and the different precedence for each row in the matrix.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class RationaleForRepetitions {

    private class PrecedenceModel {

        private int elementCount;
        private int[][] baseMatrix;

        public PrecedenceModel(int elementCount) {
            this.elementCount = elementCount;
            setBaseMatrix(elementCount);
        }

        public int getElementCount() {
            return elementCount;
        }

        public int[][] getBaseMatrix() {
            return baseMatrix;
        }

        public void setBaseMatrix(int elementCount) {
            baseMatrix = new int[elementCount][elementCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < elementCount; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < elementCount; j++) {
                    baseMatrix[i][j] = (j <= i) ? 1 : j + 1 - i; 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int numberOfElements = 8; 

        PrecedenceModel precedenceModel = new RationaleForRepetitions().new PrecedenceModel(numberOfElements);

        System.out.println("Number of elements to calculate = " + precedenceModel.getElementCount() + System.lineSeparator());
        System.out.println("Precedence Model: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < precedenceModel.getElementCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(precedenceModel.getBaseMatrix()[i]));
        }

        System.out.println(System.lineSeparator() + "Discard first and last rows (boundary cases). First row has no repetitions and last one is all repetitions." + System.lineSeparator());

        System.out.println("i -> j");
        for (int i = 1; i < (precedenceModel.getElementCount() - 1); i++) {
            System.out.print(i + " -> ");
            for (int j = i + 1; j < precedenceModel.getElementCount(); j++) {
                System.out.print(j - i + 1 + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println(System.lineSeparator());

        System.out.println("Permutations should run on each of the following results:" + System.lineSeparator());


        for (int i = 1; i < (precedenceModel.getElementCount() - 1); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < precedenceModel.getElementCount(); j++) {
                int array[] = precedenceModel.getBaseMatrix()[i].clone();
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
                for (int k = 0; k < i + 1; k++) {
                    array[k] = j - i + 1;
                }
                array[j] = 1;
                System.out.println(String.format("%s%s", Arrays.toString(array), System.lineSeparator()));

            }
            System.out.println(String.format("%2$s%2$s%2$s%1$s", System.lineSeparator(), "-------------------"));
        }

        System.out.println("Precedence Model: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < precedenceModel.getElementCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(precedenceModel.getBaseMatrix()[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

The following code is **just for displaying/printing the results properly** and it can be omitted if references from Combinatorics class are deleted.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class ApiUtils {

    public static Map<String, String> mergeMapsWithPrecedence(Map<String, String> ... higherToLowerPrecedenceMaps) {
        int mapLength = 0;
        for (Map<String, String> map : higherToLowerPrecedenceMaps) {
//          mapLength += map.size();
            mapLength = map.size() > mapLength ? map.size() : mapLength;
        }

        Map<String, String> superMap = new HashMap<>(mapLength);
        for (Map<String, String> map : higherToLowerPrecedenceMaps) {
            map.forEach((k,v) -> {
                if( ! superMap.containsKey(k) ) {
                    superMap.put(k, v);
                }
            });
        }

        return superMap;
    }

    public static <T> Map<Integer, T> getMap(T ... values) {
        Map<Integer, T> map = new HashMap<>(values.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            map.put(i, values[i]);
        }

        return map;
    }

    public static <T> List<T> getList(T ... values) {
        return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(values));
    }

    public static void appendNewLine(StringBuffer stringBuffer, String content) {
        stringBuffer
            .append(content)
            .append(System.lineSeparator());
    }

    public static void appendKeyValueNewLine(StringBuffer stringBuffer, String key, String value, String delimiter) {
        stringBuffer
            .append(key)
            .append(delimiter)
            .append(value)
            .append(System.lineSeparator());
    }

    public static List<String> replaceParameterizedList(List<String> data) {
        return
            data
                .stream()
                .filter(s -> ! ApiConstantsUtils.MISSING.equals(s))
                .map(s -> ApiConstantsUtils.NULL.equals(s) ? null : s)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static Map<String, String> replaceParameterizedMap(Map<String, String> data) {
        Map<String, String> updatedData = new HashMap<>();
        for (Entry<String, String> element : data.entrySet()) {

            if (ApiConstantsUtils.NULL.equals(element.getValue())) {
                updatedData.put(element.getKey(), null);
            } else if ( ! ApiConstantsUtils.MISSING.equals(element.getValue()) ) {
                updatedData.put(element.getKey(), element.getValue());
            }
        }

        return updatedData;
    }

    public static List<Map<String, String>> replaceParameterizedListOfMaps(List<Map<String, String>> data) {
        return
            data
                .stream()
                .map(map -> replaceParameterizedMap(map))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    /**
     * Naming conventions for methods that print nested collections:
     * 
     * Nx = (N)esting, x = level
     * Sn = (D)elimiter. n = newLine
     */
    public static <T extends Collection<?>> String collectionToStringN1Dn(Collection<T> collection) {
        return
            collection
                .stream()
                .map(list -> list.toString())
                .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
    }

    public static void printStackTrace() {
        for (StackTraceElement ste : Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()) {
            System.out.println(ste.toString());
        }
    }

    public static void creatFileInRoot(String fileContent) {
        creatFileInRoot(Arrays.asList(fileContent), "txt");
    }

    public static void creatFileInRoot(Iterable<String> fileContent) {
        creatFileInRoot(fileContent, "txt");
    }

    public static void creatFileInRoot(Iterable<String> fileContent, String extension) {
        Path outputPath = ApiConstantsUtils.OUTPUT_FOLDER;
        if(extension == null || StringUtils.isBlank(extension)) {
            extension = "txt";
        }
        String filename =
                ApiReflectionUtils.getCallerCallerClassName().getSimpleName() +
                "_" + Instant.now().toEpochMilli() +
                "." + extension;
        filename = filename.replaceAll(" ", "_");

        creatFileInRoot(outputPath, filename, fileContent);
    }

    private static void creatFileInRoot(Path outputPath, String filename, Iterable<String> fileContent) {
        outputPath.toFile().mkdirs();
        try {
            Files.write(outputPath.resolve(filename), fileContent, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW);
            System.out.println("File created: " + outputPath.resolve(filename).toAbsolutePath().toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error while attempting to create file: " + outputPath.resolve(filename).toAbsolutePath().toString());
        }
    }
}


public class ApiReflectionUtils {

    public static Class<?> getCallerClassName() {
        StackTraceElement[] stElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        for (int i = 1; i < stElements.length; i++) {
            StackTraceElement ste = stElements[i];
            if (!ste.getClassName().equals(ApiReflectionUtils.class.getName())
                    && ste.getClassName().indexOf("java.lang.Thread") != 0) {
                try {
                    return Class.forName(ste.getClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static Class<?> getCallerCallerClassName() {
        StackTraceElement[] stElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        String callerClassName = null;
        for (int i = 1; i < stElements.length; i++) {
            StackTraceElement ste = stElements[i];
            if (!ste.getClassName().equals(ApiReflectionUtils.class.getName())
                    && ste.getClassName().indexOf("java.lang.Thread") != 0) {
                if (callerClassName == null) {
                    callerClassName = ste.getClassName();
                } else if (!callerClassName.equals(ste.getClassName())) {
                    try {
                        return Class.forName(ste.getClassName());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}


import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class ApiConstantsUtils {

    public static final String CALCULATE = "calculate";
    public static final String NULL = "[NULL]";
    public static final String MISSING = "[MISSING]";
    public static final Path OUTPUT_FOLDER = Paths.get("src/main/resources/output");



    public enum ComparisonCardinality{
        ONE_TO_ONE,
        ONE_TO_MANY,
        MANY_TO_ONE,
        MANY_TO_MANY;

        public static ComparisonCardinality getElementComparisonCardinality(List<?> objectsLeft, List<?> objectsRight) {

            if (objectsLeft.size() == 1 && objectsRight.size() == 1) {
                return ONE_TO_ONE;
            } else if (objectsLeft.size() == 1 && objectsRight.size() > 1) {
                return ONE_TO_MANY;
            } else if (objectsLeft.size() > 1 && objectsRight.size() == 1) {
                return MANY_TO_ONE;
            } else if (objectsLeft.size() > 1 && objectsRight.size() == objectsLeft.size()) {
                return MANY_TO_MANY;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    public enum ComparisonOperator{
        EQUAL_TO("=", "equal"),
        DISTINCT_FROM("<>", "distinct"),
        GREATER_THAN(">", "greater"),
        LESS_THAN("<", "less");

        private String operator;
        private String keyWord;
        ComparisonOperator(String operator, String keyWord) {
            this.operator = operator;
            this.keyWord = keyWord;
        }
        public String getOperator() {
            return operator;
        }
        public String getKeyWord() {
            return keyWord;
        }
        private static Map<String,ComparisonOperator> enumValues = new HashMap<>();
        static {
            for (ComparisonOperator comparisonOperator : ComparisonOperator.values()) {
                enumValues.put(comparisonOperator.keyWord, comparisonOperator);
            }
        }
        public static ComparisonOperator getByKeyWord(String operatorKeyWord) {
            return enumValues.get(operatorKeyWord);
        }
    }

}
```